# SendInput, why doesn't simulate up arrow key?

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to simulate UP arrow key, so i used sendinput, i saw on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx UP arrow key is 0x26, but the problem is that the program simulate the press of "L" and no up arrow key, why?
Here is the code:

```
INPUT ip;
ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip.ki.time = 0;
ip.ki.wVk = 0;
ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
ip.ki.wScan =0x26; //UP ARROW key
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Comment: What does `SendInput()` returns? What does [`getLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says?

Comment: It is always a mistake to send events one by one. Create an array and inject them in one call to `SendInput`. This is explained in the documentation. I don't believe you have read it carefully enough.

Comment: And for what it is worth, there's no point grubbing around with scancodes here. Remove `KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE` and use the virtual key code, `VK_UP` in this case.

Comment: It doens't work

Comment: Yes it does. You are doing it wrong.

Comment: The problem is that i want to simulate press key in a game  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647053/sendinput-not-equal-to-pressing-key-manually-on-keyboard-in-c   and as you said don't work

Comment: That's not what is written in the question. I'm just looking at the question that was asked. If you asked the wrong question, that's really your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the *virtual key code* as the scancode, not the actual scancode.

According to [this scancode table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299374(v=vs.60).aspx) the correct value is `0x48`.

Comment: ip.ki.wScan =0X48    This simulate 8

Comment: Scancodes are hardware-dependent. The correct way to get a scancode for a virtual key is to use [`MapVirtualKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306.aspx)/[`MapVirtualKeyEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646307.aspx) with the `uMapType` parameter set to `MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC` or `MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC_EX`.

Comment: The problem is that i want to simulate press key in a game http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647053/sendinput-not-equal-to-pressing-key-manually-on-keyboard-in-c    so i must use ip.ki.wScant to move

Comment: @secon25 Did you follow the links Remy posted in his comment and read about those functions?