# Imitate hardware keypress in Python script when sending to Citrix app (SendKeys does not work)

Tags: python, c, vb.net, keyboard, citrix

I've spent much of the last two days trying to figure out how to send a Ctrl-Space to an app running on Citrix. My script is Python-based, and I have tried various solutions from SendKeys through Pywin32 and SendInput(), as well as solutions outlined in these posts among others I have long since closed:
[Generate Keyboard events in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/how-to-generate-keyboard-events-in-python)
[SendInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647053/sendinput-not-equal-to-pressing-key-manually-on-keyboard-in-c)

The issue is these all seem to be sending text or simulated keypresses, which Citrix is not recognizing. What it seems like I need to do is emulate the hardware keypress rather than sending directly to the app. Many of the solutions are in C (or similar), with which I am unacquainted.

Does anyone have a Python-based solution for this? Or a way to include C or VB.NET code in Python? There was a VB solution listed [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/310817/SendKeys-using-ScanCodes-to-Citrix) that may or may not work, but I'm not sure how to import its functionality into my Python-based script.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

EDIT: To underscore the need for direct hardware manipulation rather than simulated keypresses, I sent the following commands to the Citrix app:

```
        SendInput(Keyboard(VK_RETURN))
        SendInput(Keyboard(VK_RETURN, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
        SendInput(Keyboard(VK_CAPITAL))
        SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_L))
        SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_L, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
        SendInput(Keyboard(VK_CAPITAL, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
        SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_0))
        SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
        SendInput(Keyboard(VK_SPACE))
        SendInput(Keyboard(VK_SPACE, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
        SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_A))
        SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_A, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
        SendInput(Keyboard(VK_BACK))
        SendInput(Keyboard(VK_BACK, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
        SendInput(Keyboard(VK_CONTROL))
        SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_A))
        SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_A, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
        SendInput(Keyboard(VK_CONTROL, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
        SendInput(Keyboard(VK_LCONTROL))
        SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_V))
        SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_V, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
        SendInput(Keyboard(VK_CONTROL, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
        SendInput(Keyboard(VK_RETURN))
        SendInput(Keyboard(VK_RETURN, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
```

And I got the following output in the app: =tbd7w\=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found something that worked: [Keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/)

This successfully sent keystrokes, including modifiers, to a Citrix application. To send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SPACE</kbd> as described above is as easy as Keyboard.send('ctrl-space'). Hope this helps someone!

Comment: For me this worked with a Citrix Session.

`keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+shift+f6')`