# Why WM_KEYUP doesn't work, if WM_KEYDOWN does?

Tags: c++, winapi

`WM_KEYUP` in `PostMessage` and `SendMessage` doesn't work

I tried change ASCII code from `0x57` to `0x005701`, because my friend says it should work, but it doesn't.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int KEY_DOWN = 0x57;

int main()
{
    HWND hwnd;
    if (!(hwnd = FindWindow(L"AAAA", NULL))) {
        cout << "Couldn't find window";
    }
    else {
        Sleep(5000);
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_SETFOCUS, NULL, NULL);
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, KEY_DOWN, NULL);
    }
}
```

I want to make application that will send `WM_KEYDOWN`, and `WM_KEYUP` to application with `PostMessage` or `SendMessage` but `WM_KEYUP` doesn't work

Comment: You didn't show any code that is trying to post `WM_KEYUP`. Read the documentation for [WM_KEYDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) and [WM_KEYUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keyup), there is more involved than just the key code. However, [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513), consider using UI Automation APIs instead. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: Oh... I forgot to add this to code...
```PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, 0x57, NULL);```

Comment: What would you expect to happen, and what evidence do you have that your expectation is correct?

Comment: I expect it will click w up and down

Comment: There's no reason for you to expect that to happen. If you want to fake input, SendInput is the API to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David Heffernan said that, [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) can do this.

This is the least code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HWND hwnd;
    INPUT input[2];
    memset(input, 0, sizeof(input));
    if (!(hwnd = FindWindow(L"AAAA", NULL)))
    {
        cout << "Couldn't find window";
    }
    else
    {
        Sleep(5000);
        input[0].type = input[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

        SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);

        input[0].ki.wVk = 'W';
        input[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;
        input[1].ki.wVk = 'W';
        input[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        SendInput(2, input, sizeof(INPUT));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Put the key down and key up events into an array of length 2 and send them as a 
 single atomic unit.

Set the value of `ki.dwFlags` to control up and down states of the key.

Comment: Almost certainly a mistake to call SendInput for keyboard input with the first argument equal to 1. Build an array of input and send it as an atomic unit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I modify.

Comment: Nope. An array with both down and up events. As I said, first arg of 1 is almost always a mistake. Should be an even number.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm sorry. But I've seen some [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647053/sendinput-not-equal-to-pressing-key-manually-on-keyboard-in-c). Just reset ki. dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP and send keystrokes again to achieve the upward effect.

Comment: That is bad advice. Consider reading the official Microsoft documentation. Heck, you linked to it in the answer. The key word there is "interspersed".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What is "interspersed" ?   I did some tests with `GetAsyncKeyState`, and the result shows that the upward effect exists.

Comment: "interspersed" is a word whose meaning is described in every decent English dictionary. The only conclusion I draw from your testing is that your test cases are insufficient. You have not tested cases where interspersion occurs. Consider what happens when another program calls `SendInput` while your `Sleep(5000)` is happening.

Comment: Also, consider what happens if the second input event that you faked is processed before you call `GetAsyncKeyState`. All in all this answer contains any number of bad practises and is not to be commended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197375/discussion-between-strive-sun-msft-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: @Strive Sun - MSFT Can you explain me this code, because I can't understend? And how to do key_down using sendinput?

Comment: @FreshyCfelu The first parameter of SendInput is the operand you want to perform, because you only need two operations, key_down and key_up, so you only need two Input arrays. The second parameter is the event to insert the keyboard or mouse input stream, because you need to simulate the keyboard input, so input [0]. type = input [1]. type = INPUT_KEYBOARD, then set the relevant structure parameters in the keyboard event, set input [1]. ki. wVk ='W', which means the virtual key set is'W', followed by input [1]. ki. D. WFlags = KEYEVENT_KEYUP means that the second operation is key_up.

Comment: @Strive Sun - MSFT thank you very much!